# Ionic 2 Storage IndexedDB is emptied on airplane mode

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, indexeddb

I have an Ionic 2 app and as a requirement a client needs that he app works Offline. I'm using Ionic 2 storage specifically IndexedDB. Everything works fine in Aandroid. In iOS works fine except if the user close the app, goes to Airplane mode and opens the App.

When the user do this, all the stored data and even the DB disappears.

Any hint on why iOS do this?